# PhpMyAdmin Blank Page on fodora 22 localhost server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, fedora, lamp

I follow this guide to install LAMP server on fedora 22 workstation

[How To Install LAMP Stack (Apache, MariaDB And PHP) In Fedora 22](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-lamp-stack-apache-mariadb-and-php-in-fedora-22/)

Everything working well except phpmyadmin.

When i need access it of the browser
i see nothing (blank page)

How i can fix this issue ?

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you can get more info via 2 things
1- Enabling php display_errors in php.ini file which you can find by running

```
php --ini
```

changing display_errors to on and save it then restart apache web server and revisit phpmyadmin url which should show you the error

2- looking in apache error log which mostly located in /var/log/httpd/error.log
you can use tail -f for better tshooting

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error.log
```

Comment: thanks Amir for help , this is the result of  apache error command 
`[Thu May 28 22:19:57.174706 2015] [:error] [pid 10968] [client 192.168.1.10:35767] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 245
`

Comment: To me it looks like permission issue you can try this find session.save_path in php.ini then chown the directory to apache user or much less secure chmod it 777 just for the test . It is usually /tmp directory

Comment: yeah you right Amir ,I just copied the error_log and make a simple search i found the solution ,as you mentioned .
 1-get session.save_path    2-chown for session dir or chmod 
thanks Amir for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try running phpMyAdmin's index.php over the command line. This should give you more information about the error that causes the problem.

```
php index.php
```

Comment: thanks TimaSta , if you mean to type this command in treminal the output is `Could not open input file: index.php`